# Using a selector on href but ignoring GET variables

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, css-selectors

I want to be able to select all `<a>` tags which exactly match a given URL. If my target URL is `http://www.example.com/foo`, I want to match both:

```
<a href="http://www.example.com/foo">Blah</a>
<a href="http://www.example.com/foo?a=b">Blah</a>
```

I can't just use `$('a[href^="http://www.example.com/foo"]')` since this also matches `http://www.example.com/foo/bar`.

Is this possible with selectors, or must I iterate over the links manually?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this is what you are after...

```
$('a[href^="http://www.example.com/foo"]').filter('[href="http://www.example.com/foo"],[href^="http://www.example.com/foo?"]');
```

Basically, this should get all links that start with URL. Then filter then to be sure that only the ones exactly matching or exactly matching AND have GET parameters are returned.

Here's a jsfiddle [proving it](http://jsfiddle.net/2h5sa/).

Answer (score 0):

you could write your own selector. or, there's a plugin which allows you to use regexp: http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/regex-selector-for-jquery/